# Bags in Lego 21029 Buckingham Palace Architect

Tags: architecture

Does anyone know how many bags are in Lego set 21029 Buckingham Palace Architect set
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dy7qZFGLVNs) there are 5 unnumbered bags with few non-packed plates inside.